# How can I save cookies to my Firefox Profile in Selenium Python and load them in again next session?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, cookies

I have been using Selenium to log into a range of webpages on Firefox and search for certain keywords. Then I go to Youtube, watch a video, and close the driver after a few seconds. I was hoping to be able to observe the change in recommended videos over time due to the cookies kept in the Firefox profile, however it seems that my cookies are not being stored, I have tried the following (and many other methods) so far to start the driver:

```
ffOptions = Options()
ffOptions.headless = False
#ffOptions.add_argument('/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<new_profile>')
ffOptions.set_preference('profile', '/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<new_profile>')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = ffOptions)

driver.get(url)
```

and then later on added this to try and save the cookies to my Firefox profile:

```
current_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
for cookie in current_cookies:
    print(cookie)
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

But this doesn't save cookies to cookies.sqlite in my profile. Is there a way to save these cookies so that I can load them in again on the next session?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:
I usualy initialize the webdriver in the userdata path with an argument.
This will open the browser with all the user configurations, so your logins and cookies probably will be keept when reopen the driver.
In this case, im using Edge, but i think you can use other browsers, just find where its user data folder is.

```
# Set home and userdata path
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())
userdata = Path(f'{home}\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data')

# add option to the driver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options as EdgeOptions
opt = EdgeOptions()
opt.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={userdata}')
```